# Passing By Reference with Math

Tags: c++

I have built a soda store and im trying to add the cost of the selected soda ($2) to the total "cart" amount. I am trying to use pass by reference but I am getting an error included below.

Also I tried to add the * to the z integer in the addition function but it causes another error. How do I apply the pass by function to the math problem?

Error: [Error] invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]

```cpp
cout << "Your total is " << addition (x,&z) << '\n';
```

Main Code:

```cpp
// Menu Selection
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

 void passbyreference (int *z) {
    *z=0;
 }

int addition (int a, int b)
{ 
int z;
  z = a + b;
  return z;


}

void printcost (int z){
    cout << "your total is $" << z << endl;
}
int main()
{
  int x=2, y=2, z=0;

  char selection = ' ';
  string name = "";
  string address = "";


  //Ask user for her/his name

  cout << "Please enter your name: ";
  getline(cin, name);

  //display user name
  cout << "Hello "+ name << endl; 

  cout<< "Please enter your address: ";
  getline(cin, address);

  cout << "Your address is "+ address << endl; 

  do
    {
    cout << "\n\n Welcome to the soda shop, please choose your drink. \n\n" << endl;
    // display menu
    cout<<"My Store";
    cout<<"========" << endl;
    cout<<"1 - $2 Cola" << endl;
    cout<<"2 - $2 Root Beer" << endl;
    cout<<"3 - $2 Sprite" << endl;
    cout<<"X - Exit " <<endl<<endl;

    cout<<"Enter selection: ";
    // read user selection
    cin>>selection;    

    switch(selection)
        {
        case '1':
        cout<< "Cola" << endl;
        cout << "Your total is " << addition (x,&z) << '\n';
            break;
        case '2':
        cout<< "Root Beer" << endl;
        cout << "Your total is " << addition (x,z) << '\n';
            break;
        case '3':
        cout<< "Sprite" << endl;
        cout << "Your total is " << addition (x,z) << '\n';
            break;
        case 'X' :
        case 'x':
        cout<<"Thank you" << endl;
            break;
        // other than 1, 2, 3 and X...
        default : cout<<"Invalid selection. Please try again";
        // no break in the default case
        }
    cout<<endl<<endl;
  } while (selection!= 'X' && selection != 'x');

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is `addition` supposed to also store the running total for the sodas you have bought?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Is `addition(int a, int b)` necessary? Seems like the `+` operator would be a bit more straightforward. Looks like it wants a plain `int`, but you're sending the address-of `z` here. If you're trying to add a cart, you might just make a variable `total` in `main` and do `total += some_price`. Or keep an array of items that have been selected so far.

Comment: Read what the error says and what your code says. The error is `" invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int'"`. And the line of code it's complaining about contains addition (x,**&z**).

Comment: @CareyGregory so how do I allow it to make that conversion in working order?

Comment: @PaulRooney im not really sure

Comment: @ggorlen I am required to use 3 functions in this code, the addition code was the one showed in my Prof Brief

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you know the basics of how pointers work.

If you initialize a pointer  by `int *z;` ,  it means that z will be holding a memory address.

Then to assign the pointer to a variable ( defined as `int a = 10;` ), you can write `z = &a`.

What happens is `&a` gives the memory address of that variable and then it is assigned to `z` which means that `*z` will be giving you resolved value of the memory address which is held by z.

What you're doing is not clear but I assume that you're passing `x` and `z` to the function and you're somehow trying to update the total value in `z`.

You need to modify the `int addition (int a, int b)` to `int addition (int a, int *b)` to make it accept a pointer as a parameter and then you need use the same `*b` from the parameter to update the total value.

```
// Menu Selection
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

 void passbyreference (int *z) {
    *z=0;
 }

int addition (int a, int *b)
{ 
  *b = *b + a;
  return *b;


}

void printcost (int z){
    cout << "your total is $" << z << endl;
}
int main()
{
  int x=2, y=2, z=0;

  char selection = ' ';
  string name = "";
  string address = "";


  //Ask user for her/his name

  cout << "Please enter your name: ";
  getline(cin, name);

  //display user name
  cout << "Hello "+ name << endl; 

  cout<< "Please enter your address: ";
  getline(cin, address);

  cout << "Your address is "+ address << endl; 

  do
    {
    cout << "\n\n Welcome to the soda shop, please choose your drink. \n\n" << endl;
    // display menu
    cout<<"My Store";
    cout<<"========" << endl;
    cout<<"1 - $2 Cola" << endl;
    cout<<"2 - $2 Root Beer" << endl;
    cout<<"3 - $2 Sprite" << endl;
    cout<<"X - Exit " <<endl<<endl;

    cout<<"Enter selection: ";
    // read user selection
    cin>>selection;    

    switch(selection)
        {
        case '1':
        cout<< "Cola" << endl;
        cout << "Your total is " << addition (x, &z) << '\n';
            break;
        case '2':
        cout<< "Root Beer" << endl;
        cout << "Your total is " << addition (x, &z) << '\n';
            break;
        case '3':
        cout<< "Sprite" << endl;
        cout << "Your total is " << addition (x, &z) << '\n';
            break;
        case 'X' :
        case 'x':
        cout<<"Thank you" << endl;
            break;
        // other than 1, 2, 3 and X...
        default : cout<<"Invalid selection. Please try again";
        // no break in the default case
        }
    cout<<endl<<endl;
  } while (selection!= 'X' && selection != 'x');

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'll suggest one more thing, which is to rename your variables to some meaningful words or phrases that give a reference of what that variable is used for. This makes your code more readable.

Comment: is it possible to display how many times I selected each case?

Comment: If the number of items in the menu are less, you can simply create `countCola`, `countRB`, `countSprite`. and then `countCola = countCola + 1` for each drink below the `cout << "Your total is " << addition (x, &z) << '\n';` line.

Comment: [This is the working code](https://onlinegdb.com/rkmL7BzHH) I hope you're not cheating on your homework.

Comment: I would argue that having the code not only take the reference and alter it but also return the value is, confusing from a usability point of view. It will also make it very easy for your professor to see that you copied the answer from somewhere. It's best to either return OR alter in place.

Comment: @PaulRooney I tried to make minimum adjustments to the code. I know the code is redundant, but I didn't want to alter the code much. Hope it doesn't cause any problems 

Comment: Thank you for both of your input/help. I understand the difference between copying someone elses code and actually writing code yourself. From the resources ive been given It basically is seeing someone elses code and adapting it to work with what you want it to do although I have been struggling with this. I will do my best to learn C++ and not just copy paste someone's code

Comment: If it makes you feel better I just coded the Cout to display each count as a store cart at the end haha. Master coding on my end for sure

Answer (score 1):

See this line of code?

> cout << "Your total is " << addition (x,&z) << '\n';

Change it to this:

> cout << "Your total is " << addition (x,z) << '\n';

**Read the errors the compiler gives you and believe them.**

Comment: yes but how do i make the addition function use the pass by reference so I can build up the total each time the user (re)selects an option

Comment: @MikeyMurakami It's really not clear what it is you want to do.

Comment: @MikeyMurakami You need to study what pass by reference means.

Comment: @CareyGregory I did but as you can see I was struggling with why it wasnt working correctly. I did receive help though and fixed the error

Answer (score 0):

You don't need pass by reference for this. Nor frankly do you even need a separate function. Here's some code that does what you want

```
int main()
{
    int total = 0;
    ...
    switch(selection)
    {
    case '1':
        cout<< "Cola" << endl;
        total = total + 2; // add $2 to the total
        cout << "Your total is " << total << '\n';
        break;
    case '2':
        cout<< "Root Beer" << endl;
        total = total + 2; // add $2 to the total
        cout << "Your total is " << total << '\n';
        break;
```

etc. etc

Most important lesson though is, if you have a variable that is a total, then call it `total`, don't call it `z`.

**EDIT**

To actually create a function that uses pass by reference do this.

```
void add_to_total(int& total, int sum) // pass total by reference
{
    total = total + sum;
}
```

Then use it like this

```
add_to_total(total, 2); // add $2 to the total
```

Comment: thanks @john sadly my homework requires me to use functions and pass by reference to get a good grade :( I think we are learning how to cause self harm via the brain instead of learning how to create the simplest code to produce the results we want.